# Jupyter Notebook can open in VS code, but not in the terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My Jupyter Notebook works in Visual Studio Code, but it does not work in the terminal anymore. I cannot open through terminal and connect to local host anymore.. It always show the error that command not found though I have installed the notebook package.. What could've been the issue here? [image]

Comment: My guess is that your PATH variables are different in the two cases.  Does `which jupyter` provide an answer at the same terminal prompt? If not, then maybe you need to find the `jupyter` executable and update your PATH to include its location.

Comment: I typed in which jupyter, it did not prompt anything in the terminal  @Steve

Answer (score 0):

You pip3 install jupyter

and you run jupyter notebook with this line:
python3 -m jupyter notebook

For some reason, use jupyter notebook directly will give me the error in the above image... so I guess this solve the problem..

Comment: if you're talking about running jupyter using a python package, then the terminal has no clue what the jupyter command is..anaconda comes distributed with jupyter installed, which will allow you to run it from terminal if that's an option you're interested in